# Upgrade ios swift from 2.3 to 4

Tags: ios, swift

i have an ios project which was published to appstore before an year, now i need to update the app to appstore. My project is written in swift 2.3 can i make the changes to the app and publish it without updating the swift version ? or i need to update the swift version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you can't upload any build to AppStore that's not build with xcode 9 , which means you have to update your swift version at least to swift 3 , so use xcode 8 to convert your swift 2.3 to 3 , then open it with xcode 9 make some changes and lower **swift_version** in build settings to make the migration pretty easier

Comment: But it would be much better to upgrade to Swift 4. The changes from 3 to 4 are much less drastic than from 2 to 3. It's always best to stay current.

Comment: @rmaddy yes , the main problem is the migration to swift 3 after that everything is very easy